# Gaps in front and below of text

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble styling a small block of text to be perfectly contained within its element. No matter what I do, there seems to be space in front and below the words. I can remove the bottom gap by changing the line height but this seems like a sloppy solution depending on whether the browser decides to display arial or helvetica (I've left the font type as simply 'sans serif') as this may potentially screw up any perfect alignment I have.

CSS

```
    html, body {
        margin: 0;
        border: 0;
        padding: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        font-family: Sans-Serif;
    }

    ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    li {
        display: inline-block;
    }

    #title {
        font-size: 36px;
        font-weight: bold;
        background-color: red;
        display: inline-block;
    }
```

HTML

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
        <body>
            <div id="header">
                <ul id="title">
                    <li>
                        Test title
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

This is what currently happens:

[image: Current Situation]

This is what I would like to happen:

[image: Desired Outcome]

JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/kyuLqed8/

Comment: That's how it's supposed to look...it's the actual character glyphs that include that space.

Answer (score 0):

In css us "line-height" for text element. Look this

```css
html, body {
 margin: 0;
 border: 0;
 padding: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 font-family: Sans-Serif;
}

ul {
 list-style-type: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

li {
 display: inline-block;
}

#title {
    line-height: 25px;
 font-size: 36px;
 font-weight: bold;
 background-color: red;
 display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<body>
 <div id="header">
  <ul id="title">
   <li>
    Test title
   </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</body>
```